# How to properly create a multi-page gui in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm very new to wxpython, so this is probably an obvious question.

Let's say I wanted to create a program [like an installation wizard](https://www.bitrixsoft.com/images/install_en/env/benv_setup_1.png) which, when next is clicked, destroys the current set of widgets and creates a new set. However, the user must also be able to go back to a previous page.

Would I need classes for each page with their own `__init__`, could I just use a normal function, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of valid approaches. The most obvious would be to just use wxPython's built-in wizard which can be found in `wx.wizard`. You might want to take a look at the [documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/adv.Wizard.html), the [wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxWizard) or the wxPython demo for examples. You might also find this tutorial helpful:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/27/wxpython-a-wizard-tutorial/

Of course the wizard is a bit limited, so if you needed something that gives you more flexibility, then you might want to look at rolling your own wizard. If you went with that approach, then yes, you would probably benefit from creating a base Page class that holds your assortment of widgets. Then as each page is shown, you can either `Hide` the previous page or `Destroy` it. Personally, I would just go with hiding it unless you had a lot of widgets per page.

This tutorial might help you get started down this path:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/wxpython-how-to-create-a-generic-wizard/

Comment: So it's acceptable practice to create widgets outside of `__init__`?

Comment: Yes. A lot of people will create widgets in a specific method that is called by something in the `__init__`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I only ask because pycharm gives me the soft warning "instance attribute defined outside `__init__`, but I suppose that's not an issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure WYSIWYG editors (wxGlade, Boa Constructor) for wxPython will do this sort of thing, so I don't think it's an issue

Comment: So just to make sure I have the right idea, what you're suggesting is to instantiate all widgets in `__init__`, then `.Show()` and `.Hide()` them as necessary.

Comment: I would instantiate the first page and show it. You can instantiate the rest too if you want to, but you don't have to. You can instantiate those right before you show them. It really depends on what you're going to show and how many pages there are.